# System.OutOfMemoryException in thread

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem. This part of code returns after ~1min `System.OutOfMemoryException` error. But I can't find what exacly causes this error. I would be glad if somebody will tell me what is the reason of this issue, and how to resolve it.

Part of my thread:

```
    public void Run(object client)
    {
        TextBox tbServerResult = (client as Client).Controls.Find("tbServerResult", true).SingleOrDefault() as TextBox;
        Client tt = new Client();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i--)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            string result = tt.SendGet("xyz" + tt.getToken() + "");
            tbServerResult.AppendText(result);
        }
    }
```

SendGet method:

```
    public string SendGet(string url)
    {

        string webpageContent = "";
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    webpageContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                //tbServerResult.AppendText("\r\n" + "Server code:" + webResponse.StatusCode + " Server status description:" + webResponse.StatusDescription);
                webpageContent = "Server code:" + webResponse.StatusCode + " Server status description:" + webResponse.StatusDescription;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            webpageContent = ex.Message;
        }

        return webpageContent;
    }
```

Comment: Could you point which line throws an exception? You can also show a URL that you are requesting

Comment: Other than the `reader.ReadToEnd()` I don't see any likely candidates for an OutOfMemoryException either, but even then that would mean some pretty fast downloading if it runs out after 1 minute...

Comment: Looks suspiciously like GUI operations in non-GUI thread.

Comment: @MartinJames That should result in a different type of exception, although I agree the `AppendText` on a background thread should fail. So probably the OutOfMemoryException occurs before it actually tries to access the control.

Comment: Also, how many of these threads are you creating?  Also, what's with the sleep call anyway - just debugging?

Comment: Also, what type is 'Client'?  You get one as startup parameter, look up a textbox by name in it, then make another Client? What are you doing?

Answer (score 4):

You have line with `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i--)`

this is infinite loop.

Comment: While you are right I would have though that the `Thread.Sleep` means it shouldn't run enough to get an out of memory exception in a minute...

Comment: There is an "infinite" loop in the code, but if the error occurs after about 1 minute, that cannot be the problem. Only 1 iteration is executed per 10 seconds at maximum.